# Auto populating state after zipcode is entered by user

Tags: html, jquery

below is my code. Here my issue is while a user enters any zipcode at form. Then that zipcoode should be accessd in jQuery where state will autopopulate

**JQuery**

```
$("#InputZip").on("keyup",function(event){
   var value= $(this).val();

    if(value!=""&&value.length==5)
    {
        if(value== 80023){
                     $('#Inputstate').val("CO");
        }else{
                     $('#Inputstate').val("Worng Code");
        }
}
});
```

*html*

```
<input id="InputZip" name="Zip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">
<input id="Inputstate" name="state" placeholder="State" type="text">
```

Comment: and your problem is? your code seems valid, when enering the given value stte will be set to CO

Comment: Are the zipcodes saved  in an array ?

Comment: no it is not saved in arrey. I am using uspc api

Comment: Can you share how you are calling that API and what data is being returned from that API so that a proper answer can be provided

Comment: url = "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID='096LAKSH6389'><ZipCode ID='0'><Zip5>80023</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>"this is my api from this ia m getting this output  "BROOMFIELD
CO" so in this api you can see above i have given 80023 pin code,So this code user should give in the form zipcode field then the Jquery code should acces that zipcode

Comment: whatever zipcode user enters in the form field, that should dynamically come into the above provided jQuery code ,My issue is how to dynamically get the user entered zipcode in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
   var states = [{'pincode': 'state'......N}] //or get states from rpc call
   $("#InputZip").on("keyup",function(event){
   var value= $(this).val();

    if(value!=""&&value.length==5)
    {   var state = searchState('pincode') || false;
        if(state){
                     $('#Inputstate').val(state);
        }else{
                     $('#Inputstate').val("Worng Code");
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: here i want a zipcode to be entered by a user in form field, from there i want t access in the above JQuery to autopopulate a state

Comment: import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#url = https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=80023""
url = "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID='096LAKSH6389'><ZipCode ID='0'><Zip5>80023</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>"
response = requests.request("get",url)
print(response)
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = ET.fromstring(response.text, parser=parser)
print(root)

Comment: print(root.findall('ZipCode'))
for i in root.findall('ZipCode'):
    # product_name = getattr(child.find('productname'), 'text', None)
    city = i.find('City').text
    State = i.find('State').text
    print(city)
    print(State)

Comment: here i want to access the zipcode which is enter by user dynamically in JQuery

Comment: First of all this is wrong way ... You can submit the form and then you can get the zip code and from that u can find state.

Comment: Secondly if you still insist, try to append zip code entered by user in dom and then with etree fetch complete XML and find that XML or HTML tag and retrieve attribute

Comment: We are trying to use USPS API to get City and State attributes by passing ZIP code. API is working fine, but we need to use this API in our members registration form, where user enters ZIP code, then City and State should be auto filled in respective fields. This way user does not have to type City and State manually.

We would like to know what is the easiest and quicker way to achieve this in Django or other type web forms.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {              
    $("#InputZip").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: "zip=" + el.val(),
                success: function(result, success) {
                    $("#Inputstate").val(result.state);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

Comment: https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="096LAKSH6389"><ZipCode ID='0'><Zip5>80014</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>

80014AURORACO  "this is a url"